# Parameter sets testing path

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to validate a path in my script:

```
Param(
[Parameter(ParameterSetName="Path",
    Mandatory=$true,
    Position=0)]
    [ValidateScript({$_})]
    [String]
    $checkPath )
```

Not sure if this is the correct approach for testing a path?

It's not checking the supplied path exists.

Comment: `[ValidateScript({Test Path $_})]`? It is impossible to fail now since you have validation for just the presence of data. Only a null or empty string would fail this now.

Comment: Yes that dupe target is for multiple files but the answer is the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Checking-Path {
Param (
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName="Path",Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
    [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})]
    [String]
    $Checkpath
)

Write-Host "Path Exist"
}
```